# Modeling location data by time in Mongo

Tags: mongodb, data-modeling

I am really struggling with how to model a collection or a few collections.

I am storing location data.

Location data comes in for multiple users very frequently.
Each user can be assigned to multiple tasks.

User Model (current)

```
{
  _id: 123,
  name: "bob",
  email: "bob@gmail.com",
  address: "...."
}
```

Task Model

```
{
  _id: 456,
  name: "task 1",
  userIds: [123, ...] // multiple users per task
}

{
  _id: 789,
  name: "task 2",
  userIds: [123, ...] // user can be in multiple tasks (ie bob)
}
```

When a user submits a location I want to store that in mongo as well.  It will be timestamped.

I do NOT (if possible) want to store the users location based on a particular 'task'.  This is because my users may forgot to switch from task 1 to task 2 (say after lunch) and if I store they users location per task he would no appear in task 2 if he forgot to switch.  I realize this will require me to either 'join' the taskIds for a user(s) with locations or store the users taskIds in each location document.

My queries will filter on last N number of locations (sorted by time newest first) for each user in a given task.  IE. For all users in task 1, give me there last 10 locations.

What I have tried to model:

**Simple locations collection, one document for each location**

{ userId: 123, timestamp: {//time}, location: { //geo } }

This is extremely simple model (index on userId and timestamp).  However query based on task becomes difficult.  To do it I first need to find all users in that task, then do another query to find all locations with those user ids.  Also getting last 10 locations for user seems impossible in this model.  I can use the aggregate framework to group by user, but with that framework I have to limit before the group.  Meaning limit all locations regardless of user to say 10.  That will give me first 10 sorted locations, not first 10 sorted locations for each user.

I could add all tasks a user is a part of for each location entry.  However any time a user is added to a new task I have to update a lot of location entries.  Even with that I still cannot get N number of locations for each user with this model

So bad model right :/

**Group locations (array) for each user**

I also tried to have one document per user, in that document have a list of tasks that user is part of (requires update to doc when users is added to task. Also keep a list of locations for that user.

User location Model:

```
{
  userId: 123,
  teamIds: [456, 789], // all tasks user is a part of
  locations: [{loc1}, {loc2}, .... {locN}] // sorted by time
}
```

This is closer to how I query.  Since each doc is for a single user grouping is natural per document.  I can query for all users that are part of team 456, and splice array to get N number of locations per document.

However this has a huge problem.  The locations array has to be limited or I will run into the document size limit.

**Group locations (array) for each user, one doc per day**

I could use the above model but to avoid the doc size limit, I could limit the amount of locations for each user doc to one day. IE one doc per user per day.

```
{
  userId: 123,
  timestamp: // day timestamp
  taskIds: [456, 789], // all tasks user is a part of
  locations: [{loc1}, {loc2}, .... {locN}] // sorted by time
}
```

Problem here again is that each time a user is added/removed from a task I have to update a lot of documents, to add/remove that task.

Really trying to solve these 2 problems:

1. Store/Query locations such that I can group by user and limit the amount of locations per user to last N locations.
2. Avoid join on users team Ids when I am finding those locations.

Lastly I know at this point there might be suggestions to not use mongo to model this data.  Although I might tend to agree at this point :), I am not at liberty to switch my database.

Still hoping there might be a 'workable' solution to model this type of data and still have good query performance without too much work (time/performance) on each insert/query.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still fuzzy on exactly what the relationship between locations and tasks is, I think, and what your overall objective is, but if you have users assigned to a task, the users visit various locations, and you want to find the past `N` locations that a given user (or all users) visited as part of a specific task, why not make the document represent a particular user on a particular task at a particular location:

```
{
    "user_id" : 0
    "task_id" : 99,
    "location" : "Switzerland"
    "time" : ISODate("2015-02-04T20:34:30.942Z")
}
```

Your query for last 10 locations for a single user on a single task is

```
db.test.find({ "user_id" : user_id, "task_id" : task_id }).sort({ "time" : -1 }).limit(10)
```

Does this work? If not, can you explain clearly what operations or requirements are not compatible with this structure? It's very hard to understand your requirements from your question, so maybe this attempt at an answer will help coax a better explanation and I can edit the answer with something more helpful once I understand your use case better.